# Google Drive api uploads file name as "Untitled"

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, google-drive-api, google-apps

I can upload file to google drive from my website, but my problem is it will show the file as Untitled after uploading.

How can I add or post title to the uploading file.

Thanks,

My Code:

```
public string UploadFile(string accessToken, byte[] file_data, string mime_type)
    {
        try
        {
            string result = "";
            byte[] buffer = file_data;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media");

            request.Method = "POST";

            request.ContentType = mime_type;
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);

            var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(file_data, 0, file_data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//Get error here
            if(webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();//parse token from result

                var jLinq = JObject.Parse(result);

                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jLinq.ToString());

                webResponse.Close();

                return jObject["alternateLink"].ToString();
            }

            return string.Empty;


        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I used RestSharp for uploading a file to google drive.

```
    public static void UploadFile(string accessToken, string parentId)
    {
        var client = new RestClient { BaseUrl = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/") };

        var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&access_token={0}", accessToken), Method.POST);

        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\mypdf.pdf");

        var content = new { title = "mypdf.pdf", description = "mypdf.pdf", parents = new[] { new { id = parentId } }, mimeType = "application/pdf" };

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

        request.AddFile("content", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), "content", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        request.AddFile("mypdf.pdf", bytes, "mypdf.pdf", "application/pdf");

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) throw new Exception("Unable to upload file to google drive");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with out using the google.apis dlls isnt that easy.  You need to send the meta data before you send the rest of the file. For that you need to use uploadType=multipart

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart

This should get you started sorry its a wall of code.  I havent had time to create a tutorial for this yet.

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(pFilename);
//Createing the MetaData to send
List<string> _postData = new List<string>();
_postData.Add("{");
_postData.Add("\"title\": \"" + info.Name + "\",");
_postData.Add("\"description\": \"Uploaded with SendToGoogleDrive\",");
_postData.Add("\"parents\": [{\"id\":\"" + pFolder + "\"}],");
_postData.Add("\"mimeType\": \"" + GetMimeType(pFilename).ToString() + "\"");
_postData.Add("}");
string postData = string.Join(" ", _postData.ToArray());
byte[] MetaDataByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// creating the Data For the file
byte[] FileByteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pFilename);

string boundry = "foo_bar_baz";
string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart" + "&access_token=" + myAutentication.accessToken;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/related; boundary=\"" + boundry + "\"";

// Wrighting Meta Data
string headerJson = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Type: {1}\r\n\r\n",
                boundry,
                "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
string headerFile = string.Format("\r\n--{0}\r\nContent-Type: {1}\r\n\r\n",
                boundry,
                GetMimeType(pFilename).ToString());

string footer = "\r\n--" + boundry + "--\r\n";

int headerLenght = headerJson.Length + headerFile.Length + footer.Length;
request.ContentLength = MetaDataByteArray.Length + FileByteArray.Length + headerLenght;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerJson), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(headerJson));   // write the MetaData ContentType
dataStream.Write(MetaDataByteArray, 0, MetaDataByteArray.Length);                                          // write the MetaData


 dataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerFile), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(headerFile));   // write the File ContentType
        dataStream.Write(FileByteArray, 0, FileByteArray.Length);                                  // write the file

        // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline

        dataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(footer), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(footer));
        dataStream.Close();

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Exception uploading file: uploading file." + ex.Message;

        }
```

If you need any explinations beyond the comments let me know. I strugled to get this working for a month.  Its almost as bad as resumable upload.

Comment: Hi, very thanks its working for me. I am searching more than 2 days. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution of the given problem and previously I was putting uploadType=resumable that causes the given issue and when I used uploadType=multipart problem is resolved...